# Create a comma-separated number string within a.txt file

Tags: python

I would like you to help me insert into a file.txt called useless.txt a comma-separated number sequence, follows the code. Example that should be inside the file: 0001 => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
I can't put the information I want into the file. the file is blank.

```
cont = 0
def contador(i,f,p):
    print(f'A contagem de {i} até {f} de {p} em {p}')
    if i < f:
        cont = i
        print('\n\n000=>')
        while cont <= f:
            print(f'{cont}', end=' ')
            cont += p
        print('FIM!')
    else:
        cont = i
        while cont >= f:
            print(f'{cont}', end=',')
            cont -= p
        print('FIM!')

print('Agora é sua vez, personalize um contador:')
i = int(input('Inicio: '))
f = int(input('Fim:    '))
p= int(input('Passo:   '))

arquivo = open(input('Nome do arquivo a ser editado:'), 'r')
texto = arquivo.readlines()
texto.append(input(contador(i, f,p)))
arquivo = open(input(contador(i, f,p)), 'w')
arquivo.writelines(texto)
arquivo.close()
contador(i, f,p)
```

Comment: Try [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: ok @FredLarson thank you

Comment: @RicardoJMSistemas We already know what you want now. We want to know where you got stuck, don't just put the code without explanation.

Comment: @eyllanesc I can't put the information I want into the file. the file is blank

Comment: @RicardoJMSistemas This important information should indicate it in your question. Read [ask], [answer] and review the [tour]

Comment: @RicardoJMSistemas One last recommendation, in this community the language to be used is English, so it is recommended that your code (code, comments, strings, etc.) be written in that language so that everyone can easily understand your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you make your function with print only, but no return. It means, it printing results, but it not put the result inside texto.append = ....

texto.append = input are wrong. texto.append(str) are correct.

open(input... also wrong. correct: variable=open(filename,'w')

example:

```
cont = 0

def contador(i, f, p):
    global temp
    temp.append(f'A contagem de {i} até {f} de {p} em {p}')
    temp.append('\n\n000=>')
    if i < f:
        cont = i
        numeros_contados=''
        while cont <= f:
            numeros_contados = numeros_contados+f'{cont},'
            cont += p
        temp.append(numeros_contados)
        temp.append('\nFIM!\n')
    else:
        cont = i
        numeros_contados = ''
        while cont >= f:
            numeros_contados = numeros_contados+f'{cont},'
            cont -= p
        temp.append(numeros_contados)
        temp.append('\nFIM!\n')
    return


print('Agora é sua vez, personalize um contador:')
i = int(input('Inicio: '))
f = int(input('Fim:    '))
p = int(input('Passo:   '))

nomarq = input('Nome do arquivo a ser editado:')
arquivo = open(nomarq, 'r')
texto = arquivo.readlines()
temp = texto
contador(i, f, p)
arquivo = open(nomarq, 'w')
for a in temp:
    arquivo.write(a)
arquivo.close()
```

Comment: Hey man. A suggestion: Facebook groups: Python Brasil - Programadores. (Teriam respondido rapidamente lá). Da uma votada na minha resposta como boa, tentando crescer meus pontos aqui. Valeu.... Mais uma coisa, invista no seu inglês, muito importante em programação.